# Why Different Views When Run On a Real Device and the emulator

Tags: android, xml

I have Just Created Simple Screen Contains and Edit Text and a custom num pad keyboard my problem is when I the project on the emulator it shows a view of screen like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYmuf.png)
but when I run on a real device it shows like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYgAr.png)

all I need I want the same View in all Devices like the one in the emulator

this is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rlp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pKeyBoardId"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:editable="false">
    </EditText>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/id_search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/exact"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pAmountKeyBoardId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlp"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:editable="false">
    </EditText>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/n1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>

        <Button
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:id="@+id/n2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>
        <Button
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:id="@+id/n3"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>
        <Button
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/n4"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>
        <Button
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/n5"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>
        <Button
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:id="@+id/n6"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>
        <Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/n7"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>
        <Button
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/n8"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>
        <Button
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/n9"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>

        <Button
            android:text="CLR"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn3_border"/>

        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/n0"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>

        <Button
            android:text="."
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4_border"/>

    </GridLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Apply"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: because of pixel density

Comment: @phpdroid how can I solve this?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Harooney create a custom layout for devices with higher pixel density. It's well documented, a single google search is all you need

Comment: It looks like there is not enough space on the screen of your physical device. The right margin therefore seems to be too big. You can try Constraint Layout, which adds some flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok use [this tool click here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_ac_unit) to create your icons this will make sure you have icons for all resolutions, when you create icon make sure to copy all folders that will contain all (`xxxhdpi` `xhdpi` `hdpi` `mdpi`) in your `drawable`folder and android will automatically use right image cheers!

Comment: I just using one Icon these are buttons and the backGround contains just a resource drawable file

Comment: just do what is written above!

Comment: I tride this compile it works
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1"

Answer (score 0):

Just compile the previus version for a GridLayout

```
compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1"
```